# Как сделать, чтобы php-curl не возвращал ответ, если на странице ошибка

Tags: php, curl

Как сделать, чтобы php-curl не возвращала страницу, если эта страница с ошибкой. Например: curl выполняет запросы к php странице, все ок, но через некоторое время домен прекратит работу и curl вернет страницу с ошибкой, как сделать, чтобы он фиильтровал эти страницы с ошибками и если есть ошибки то не возвращал ничего

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST           => 1,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $data
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if(!$response){
     echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch) . ' - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch) . "in $url";

}else{
    echo $response;
}
```

Comment: что в Вашем понимании "ошибка php-curl" ? что вы уже сделали/пытались сделать по данному вопросу?

Comment: под ошибкой я имею в виду страницу, в которой пишеться ошибка, типа "This domain has expired. error"

Comment: пример кода, котрый вы написали?

Comment: Если страница возвращается с кодом отличным от 200, то можно проанализировать `curl_info()`. А вообще я бы советовал пользоваться guzzle для работы. Там уже всё есть